# JSON.parse ends up in 'missing ) after argument list'

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to pass an php array to js. For this purpose I use json_encode an then in js JSON.parse().

Now the Problem ist, that JSON.parse trow an exception  'missing ) after argument list'. I guess it's apostrophes in numbers (number_format > CHF).

clippings:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    var prices = JSON.parse('<?= $this->prices_json; ?>'); ...
```

... "offsetdruck_4f":{"1s":"583.82","2s":"1'090.09"}...

1. have single quotes to be escaped? If so, how best to do it?
2. is json_encode an then in js JSON.parse the best practice to pass an php-Array to js (at a template)? If not, how best to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> have single quotes to be escaped?

Single quotes inside a JavaScript string literal that is delimited with single quotes do have to be escaped.

… and that is what you have: `'data with ' and then at the end'`.

> If so, how best to do it?

To not use a JavaScript string literal at all.

JSON is a subset of JavaScript literal notation, so just treat it as JavaScript. Don't try wrapping it in a string and then explicitly parsing it.

```
var prices = <?= $this->prices_json; ?>;
```

Comment: Your second answer is not very clear to me. I don't see any other reasonable possibility to pass a larger array to js.

1. php calculates the prices 
2. in the frontend the prices are displayed in the template with echo.
nothing special, 

but 
3. in the frontend the parameters can be changed (e. g. digital or offset) and thus the price changes.

and so I grab the new price by reference.
example:
`$ (' #price_total'). text (prices[' offsetprint_4f'][1s]);`

Comment: @simi — I only gave one answer … and it has an example of the small change you need to make to your code.

Comment: Now I've seen it and understood your statement. And it works for me too. But now I can't explain it: how can I assign a "serialized array" to a variable `var prices = <?= $this->prices_json; ?>;` and still access it with a reference `$ (' #price_total'). text (prices[' offsetprint_4f'][1s]);` (without unserialize the array)?

Comment: It's JavaScript source code. It gets executed like any other JS.

Answer (score 1):

try php: addslashes(json_encode($php array))

Answer (score 0):

> have single quotes to be escaped? If so, how best to do it?

json_encode should escape everything needs to be escaped.

> is json_encode an then in js JSON.parse the best practice to pass an php-Array to js (at a template)? If not, how best to do it?

You should use json_encode in order to be sure that the output is correct. Do not rely on default array output. It has nothing to do with JSON.

You don't need to use JSON.parse here at all.

```js
var prices = <?= json_encode($this->prices_json); ?>;
```

Comment: Guys, could you please explain why have you down-voted? 
This code must work fine:

  var prices = <?= json_encode($this->prices_json); ?>;

Comment: @simi, have you tried to run my snippet? I'm convinced that you don't need to use JSON.parse at all.

Comment: I still don't understand why the answer is downvoted. It's the most optimal way to inject PHP data to JS code.

Comment: The live code example doesn't work because it doesn't run PHP and it is stupid to run `json_encode` over a string of JSON.

Comment: @Quentin, 1) please respect other users of this site 2) We should point to the author the main problem: he doesn't need to use JSON.parse, because json_encode generate the output already prepared for JS usage. This is what I wanted to show him. Name of the variable doesn't guarantee the type of the value. Seams like he has array there.

Comment: If it was an array, then outputting it would print `Array` which has no apostrophes in it, so the error the question is asking about would not occur.